Unable to serialize unknown type: <class 'beanie.odm.fields.BackLink'>
I am new to using Beanie and I'm trying to model nested categories as part of a FastAPI app. Here's how I modeled the category collection:
from pydantic import Field, BaseModel
from typing import Optional, Annotated, List
from beanie import Document, Link, BackLink, PydanticObjectId, WriteRules
from datetime import datetime, timezone

class CategoryBase(Document):
    name: Annotated[str, Indexed(unique=True)] = Field(max_length=100)
    description: Optional[str] = Field(max_length=800, default=None)
    options: Optional[List[str]] = Field(default_factory=list)

class CategoryIn(CategoryBase):
    parent: Optional[PydanticObjectId] = Field(default=None)
    children: Optional[List[PydanticObjectId]] = Field(default_factory=list)

class Category(CategoryIn):
    parent: Optional[Link["Category"]] = Field(default=None)
    children: Optional[List[BackLink["Category"]]] = Field(default_factory=list, 
                                                           original_field="parent")
    date_created: datetime = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    date_modified: datetime = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    
    class Settings:
        name = "categories"

I created an endpoint to create a "Category". When I send a payload to it, a new document is created, but I encountered an error.
Here's the internal code that interacts with the database:
class CategoryOps:
    def __init__(self, _id: PydanticObjectId):
        self.id = _id
    
    async def get_category(self):
        cat = await Category.get(self.id)
        return cat

    async def get_parent(self):
        cat = await self.get_category()
        parent = (await Category.get(cat.parent) if cat else None)
        return parent

    async def get_children(self):
        cat = await self.get_category()
        children = ([await Category.get(child_id) for child_id in cat.children]
                    if cat.children 
                    else [])
        return children

class CategoryRepo:
    @staticmethod
    async def create(cat: CategoryIn) -> Category:
        parent, children = None, []
        
        if cat.parent:
            parent = await CategoryOps(cat.parent).get_category()
            cat.parent = parent
        
        if cat.children:
            children = [await CategoryOps(c).get_category() for c in cat.children]
            cat.children = children
        
        new_category = Category(**cat.dict())
        await new_category.save(link_rule=WriteRules.WRITE)       
        await new_category.sync()
        
        return new_category

I expect that when I pass a payload including a parent ID, the parent's children field will automatically be populated with the link to the newly created category. Similarly, if the payload includes children IDs, I expect each child's parent field to be populated with the ID of the newly created category.
However, I get the following error:
Unable to serialize unknown type: <class 'beanie.odm.fields.BackLink'>

How can I resolve this issue ?

Have you found the solution? Facing same issue.

Same... Pydantic is such a diva!! The cure somehow always feels worse than the disease...
